# jquery replace html tag before loading page

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I want to replace a HTML tag with another, when loading a page, without showing original tag. For example I have a tag with class named header.

```
<h2 class="header">Original Tag</h2>
```

and I want to replace with another tag without showing original tag, 
for example :

```
<div id="new-header" class="new-header">New Tag</div>
```

I use of this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var orgHeader = $(".header");   
        orgHeader.replaceWith($("#new-header").html()); 
    });
</script>
<div id="newheader" class="header">
   <h3>I'm new.</h3>
</div>
```

But, at first show the original tag and then remove it, and show new tag.

Comment: You can't do this before loading the page as that's not how client-side JS works. You also can't have mis-matching opening/closing tags

Comment: You could use CSS to hide the h2 element so it doesn't show. Then use JS to do the manipulation and change the CSS to show the element.

Comment: Why does your code use `new-header` and `newheader` in a way that appears to be interchangeable?  Furthermore, why are you showing the "original" element at all if your goal is to immediately replace it without ever having shown it?

Comment: Thanks. Please share an example, if possible. My main problem is that, I want to hide original tag and then show new tag, without showing original tag ,Even for a moment.

Comment: The main goal of this question is for replaceing nopcommerce Top menu with my menu.

Comment: @HamidN.CH the HTML must load before the JavaScript can be executed. So there is no way to remove/hide an element until after the page has loaded. You can try with native JS yet you might encounter missing elements if the JS loads before the target element.

Answer (score 0):

With `orgHeader.replaceWith($("#new-header").html());` you're replacing the original element with the HTML content of `#new-header`.
But what you want to do is to replace it with `#new-header` itself so you should use `$().outerHTML()` instead
Like this

```
orgHeader.replaceWith($("#new-header").outerHTML());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
var h2 = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0]
var div =  document.createElement('div')
div.classList.add('new-header');
div.innerHTML = 'New Tag';
h2.parentNode.insertBefore(div , h2);
h2.parentNode.removeChild(h2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="header">Original Tag</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you cannot execute JavaScript/jQuery before the page loads. The best you can do is reduce load time so that it is faster than the User can perceive.

```js
$(function() {
  var origHeader = $(".header");
  var newHeader = $("<h2>", {
    class: "new-header"
  }).html("New Header");
  origHeader.replaceWith(newHeader);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="header">Original Tag</h2>
```